# XAML x:Name on code

Tags: wpf

Ok, the problem is that I have a few GridViewColumns, which don't implement a Name property, but, I can always of course set the x:Name property to them. How ever, I need to get them by this name on code, sort of like

```
foreach(GridViewColumn column in this.ColumnCollection)
{
    if(column.(x:Name Property) == "columnName")
        return column
}

return null
```

I did solve this by using a custom column "NamedGridViewColumn" that inherits from GridViewColumn and implements a Name property, but it would still be interesting to know how to get the x:Name on code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
column.GetValue(NameProperty).ToString() == "columnName"
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Mhh thats strange. It worked on my machine (admittedly not with GridViewColumns but with a TextBlock).

Comment: There's a difference between "Name" (NameProperty) and "x:Name".